# Retrieving a value from a RECORD

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

In a plpgsql function, I have a variable of type record:

> my_rec RECORD;

This record contains a row from an arbitrary table, so I do not know the columns before it is executed.
However, I do have the name of at least one of the columns available as a varchar.

The question is: How do I retrieve the value for a given column from my_rec?

Comment: Have you tried some SELECT statement with the given column? You don't need to know all columns to write such a statement. (Not sure if applicable though, never used RECORD's).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `hstore` to work with `record`s with dynamic columns in `PL/PgSQL` functions:

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_fn(col_name text) RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE 
  input_row record;
  col_value text;
BEGIN
  SELECT INTO input_row 
    * 
  FROM ( VALUES ('a','b','c',1) ) AS dummyrow(col1,col2,col3,intcol);

  SELECT INTO col_value
    hstore(input_row) -> col_name;

  RETURN col_value;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

`hstore` is an extension, but it's an extension that's been bundled with PostgreSQL since 8.3 and has been installable using `CREATE EXTENSION` since 9.1. The record-to-hstore conversion has been supported since something like 8.4 or 9.0.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do this in plpgsql.  I did a bit of testing for you and tried to make a "EXECUTE SELECT" solution work, such as:

```
 EXECUTE 'select $1.' || quote_ident(the_param) USING my_rec INTO my_var;
```

This does not work for me and I get:

```
 could not identify column "{{param_value here}}" in record data type
```

[Here](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2006-09/msg01250.php) is a very similar question from a few years ago saying that it is not possible with plpgsql.  Per it's suggestion, it appears that it should be possible with some other languages.  Quoting Tom Lane's answer:

> There is no way to do that in plpgsql.  You could do it in the other PLs
>   (eg plperl, pltcl) since they are not as strongly typed as plpgsql.

Comment: I do not know the name of the column, it is passed as a parameter when the function is called.

Comment: Sorry... I was confused by your question. I thought you were saying that you did know they name of the column.  I will revise my answer accordingly.